# How to change the default label positions of connectors in Enterprise Architect

Tags: position, label, uml, diagram, enterprise-architect

I'm drawing activity diagram by `Enterprise Architect 12`. The diagram type is **Activity** under **UML Behavioral**. I found the positions of the labels of connectors are close to the target element as shown in the picture. It's very confusing.

How to change the default label positions to make them close to the source element as shown in picture?

Or is there any easy way to change the label of connector from `Target Top Label` to `Source Top Label`?

[image]

Comment: N.B. Inside an `Activity` you use `Action`s for the single steps. An `Activity` is a sequence of steps itself. Unfortunately `Action` and `Activity` have the same shape.

Answer (score 4):

Better you use `Guards` for the label which you find in the `Constraints` tab. These appear in the middle label position and enclosed in square brackets. This is actually what you want to show.

[image]

**For your amusement here's my original answer**

There is no way to change the label position the way you want it out-of-the-box. You will need to write a script to do that.

There are two ways to accomplish such a script. The most comfortable is to use an add-in that responds to `EA_OnPostNewConnector`. You would then need to check whether the connector is one from a `Decision` to an `Action` and move the label accordingly.

The second one is to have a simple script (you might edit in EA's scripting window) that you run for an open diagram to scan for all `Decisions` in a diagram and alter the label position accordingly.

**Altering the label**

Once you got a connector from a `Decision` to an `Action` at hand you will need to change the label position like this:

- get the according connector from `DiagramLinks` since it has the label position
- get the element IDs from `Connector.ClientID` and `.SupplierID` and retrieve the elements with `Respository.GetElementByID(<id>)`
- assign both elements to either `decision` or `action` by looking into the `Element.Type`
- get the according `DiagramObject`s from the diagram which match the both elements (so you can get their position on the diagram)
- now it's time for a little trigonometry: the position (`DiagramElement.Left`, `.Right`, `.Top` and `.Bottom` contain the appropriate coordinates) of the two elements makes out a vector at which end you calculate (I will leave you some fun) the label position where you think it should go
- finally you take this coordinate and put it into the label position (see below).

The label position is stored in `DiagramObject.Geometry`. This is a semicolon separated string where one tag is `LRT=<colon-list>;`. `<colon-list>` itself is a colon-separated list where two are something like `OX=-1:OY=-71:` and represent the label position. This is a position relative to the "normal" position where the label is placed initially by EA.

So all in all: lot's of fun awaiting you :-/

Comment: @_@~~~
Never used script before.

I'm wondering is there any easy way to change the label of connector from `Target Top Label` to `Source Top Label`.

Comment: No. EA shows the ControlFlow note at this label position. If you change the label to appear in another label (there are 6 if I count right) the GUI will not show it as you need it.